Pytest-BDD with Xray feature files leads to Traceback and unexpected collection
I have a repository that includes :
Root dir 
    - Tests
          - test_1.py
          - test_2.py
    - features
          - 1_xray_ticket.feature

test_1.py is used for API testing, test_2.py is used for UI testing
they are built somewhat similar -
from pytest_bdd import scenarios, given, when, then, parsers
import pytest

scenarios("path/to/features/folder")


the rest of the logic (given when then)


When I trigger the pytest with the command -
python -m pytest -k / -m "tag from the feature file"
It shows collection from both test files instead of only collecting the relevant sentences from the .py files
Am I missing something? Do I need to change one of my commands?
I tried multiple paths in Scenarios() option but nothing worked.
Also tried using both -m and -k but again, nothing worked.
